# Trouble connecting to a remote MySQL database, via SSH-tunnel, using Python 3.6?

Tags: python, mysql, ssh-tunnel

I'm attempting to log into a MySQL server in python. I'm able to easily access this serve using MySQL Workbench and the same credentials, but I get an error when using the following code:

```
import MySQLdb as db
import sshtunnel
import pandas as pd
sshtunnel.SSH_TIMEOUT = 5.0
sshtunnel.TUNNEL_TIMEOUT = 5.0

with sshtunnel.SSHTunnelForwarder(
    ('accesspoint.fake.com', 22),
    ssh_username='Tony',
    ssh_password='pwtony',
    remote_bind_address=('180.45.89.0', 3306)) as server:

    conn = db.connect(host='180.45.89.0',
                           port=server.local_bind_port,
                           user='Tony',
                           password='pwtony',
                           db='all_data')
```

Error message:

```
--------------------------------------------------------
OperationalError       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-ca168ce0a4a7> in <module>()
      9                            user='Tony',
     10                            password='pwtony',
---> 11                            db='all_data')

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py in Connect(*args, **kwargs)
     84     """Factory function for connections.Connection."""
     85     from MySQLdb.connections import Connection
---> 86     return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
     87 
     88 connect = Connection = Connect

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py in __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    202         self.waiter = kwargs2.pop('waiter', None)
    203 
--> 204         super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
    205         self.cursorclass = cursorclass
    206         self.encoders = dict([ (k, v) for k, v in conv.items()

OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '180.45.89.0' (110)")
```

Would appreciate any help :)

Comment: Try `127.0.0.1` as the `host`, or extract it from `server` like you did for the port.

Comment: Also you might want to try define a different local bind port, MySQL is known to react strange when connecting to local port 3306.

Comment: @KlausD. HOLY SMOKES! Changing host to 127.0.0.1 worked! Could you please explain to me what this address is and why it worked? Also, would it be possible for you to submit this as an answer for me to accept? Thank you so much!